# Why does this code use .replaceWith instead of just .html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The code below comes from a tutorial I'm doing on Udemy.
Any idea why it replaces the entire form with `.replaceWith` instead of just popping the AJAX response into its own designated area?

It seems needlessly complicated. What am I missing?

So here's the form that sends the AJAX request

```
<div id="stock-lookup">

  <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id:'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock,
                           params[:stock],
                           placeholder: 'Stock Ticker Symbol',
                           autofocus: true,
                           class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success') do %>
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Look up a stock
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <%= render 'common/spinner' %>

  <% if @stock %>
    <div id="stock-lookup-results" class="well results-block">
      <strong>Symbol: </strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
      <strong>Name: </strong> <%= @stock.name %>
      <strong>Price: </strong> <%= @stock.price %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="stock-lookup-errors"></div>

</div>
```

and here's the js that handles it

```
var init_stock_lookup;

init_stock_lookup = function() {
    ...
    $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data, stat) {
        $('#stock-lookup').replaceWith(data);
        init_stock_lookup();
    });

    $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:error', function(evt, xhr, stat, err) {
        hide_spinner();
        $('#stock-lookup-results').replaceWith('');
        $('#stock-lookup-errors').replaceWith('Stock was not found.');
    });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    init_stock_lookup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest, It seems like the entire form is replaced with the lookup result.  It's a design choice to make the page feel interactive without reloading the entire page.  I personally wouldn't do it that way as it restricts multiple subsequent lookups.  However, this approach can be used to steer the user through interactive logic.

In terms of replacing another element with the result, it's easy to just create another element and insert it after the the form.

Comment: there is a line that resets the listener on the form so it can be used again... which is part of the needless complexity I was wondering about